# SQL Server - a nested SELECT applying calculations to various columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

My current query is quite simple and looks like this: `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM METRICS`. I need to change the query to get the same columns from the table but also applying a calculation to some of the columns leaving the same column names.

For example, this function `CONVERT(INT, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', metric_1)) % 10` will be applied to `metric_1` column and `(metric_2 * 0.9) / 100` to `metric_2` column.

It seems that this will require a nested SELECT statement. But how should it look like combined with the above statement?

I need to keep only all the existing columns with the original names and just change the values of some columns applying the functions. There are about 100 columns, so listing each column in SELECT will not work in this case. And I have a read only access to the table so can't use ALTER statements.

Comment: Using `TOP` without `ORDER BY` rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can add columns as needed to the result set by adding expressions in the column list. For example, you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 100
  *,
  CONVERT(INT, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', metric_1)) % 10 as formula1,
  (metric_2 * 0.9) / 100 as formula2
FROM METRICS
ORDER BY ...
```

This query provides all the existing columns plus two extra ones: `formula1` and `formula2`.

Now, if you want to **replace** the existing columns you need to omit the `*`. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 100
  CONVERT(INT, HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', metric_1)) % 10 as metric_1,
  (metric_2 * 0.9) / 100 as metric_2
FROM METRICS
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: The thing is that I need to keep only the existing columns with the original names and just change the values of some columns

Comment: There are about 100 columns, so listing each column in SELECT will not work in this case

Comment: @samba It should work well. A hundred columns is no biggie for a database. You'll need to write them all, once by one, though. Another option is to create a view using the query, so you don't need to type the formulas each time.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to rename the added columns shown in your 1st example (formula1, formula2 to metric_1, metric_2) and replace the old values with the calculated ones?

Comment: This question is not clear to me anymore. With your reputation I would assume you know how to ask. Do you want to query the table, or to update the table? This answer shows you how to query the table and apply formulas on the fly.

Comment: I thought of something like we're using in spark with a withColumn() / withColumnRenamed()